# Inaccuracy when using SUM function on DECIMAL column

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

When using MySQL SUM function on a DECIMAL (12.5) column, there is an error in the value generated due to inaccuracy, behaving like a column sum of type FLOAT.

I performed tests on MySQL 5.6 and 5.7, where I had the same problem on both versions.

The amount column is of type DECIMAL(12,5).

```
SELECT SUM(IF(o.operator='-', -(s.amount), s.amount)) as total
FROM stock s
INNER JOIN operators o ON s.operator_id = o.id;
```

The result by return is 701.74999, but should be 701.75000.

Comment: Please try the following to see what you get: SELECT o.Operator, SUM(s.amount) FROM stock s INNER JOIN operatros o ON s.operator_id=o.id GROUP BY o.operator

Comment: Values are returned: -13932.92001 and 14634.67000

Comment: Do you believe that these values are correct or not?

Comment: The total inventory issue records are incorrect because there are no records with the 5th decimal digit.

Comment: Older versions of MySQL used to do internal casts to float, but this should not be the case in versions 5.6 and 5.7 - have you tried the same data in different engines (so MyISAM vs InnoDB for example)?

Comment: Also, as You have specified the column as DECIMAL with 5 decimal places, *all* values have a 5th decimal digit, I think you mean that none of them are non zero. You can check with SELECT s.amount from Stock s WHERE ((s.amount*1000)-ROUND(s.amount*1000, 0))<>0